# Calling gdal_pansharpen.py from another Python script?

Tags: python, gdal, pansharpening

Has anyone been able to successfully call `gdal_pansharpen.py` from your own Python script?

I have successfully used rasterio to combine my R, G, and B bands, but would like to perform a pansharpen on the final image using the `gdal_pansharpen` command.

How did you manage to make the call?

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186847/1446289. Or possibly this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3781869/1446289

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### For older versions of GDAL:

Ensure `gdal_pansharpen.py` is in your python path. You *may* need to add it by setting the `PYTHONPATH` env var before running your script, or  within your script, i.e. `sys.path.append('gdal_pansharpen/directory')`.

```
from gdal_pansharpen import gdal_pansharpen 
gdal_pansharpen(['', '-b', '1', '-b', '2', '-b', '3', 'input_pan.tif', 'input_multi.tif', 'output_pansharpened.tif'])
```

### For GDAL == 3.2

```
from osgeo.utils import gdal_pansharpen
gdal_pansharpen(
    pan_name='input_pan.tif',    
    spectral_names=['input_multi.tif'], 
    band_nums=[1, 2, 3],
    dst_filename='output_pansharpened.tif')
```

### For GDAL >= 3.3:

```
from osgeo_utils import gdal_pansharpen
gdal_pansharpen(
    pan_name='input_pan.tif',    
    spectral_names=['input_multi.tif'], 
    band_nums=[1, 2, 3],
    dst_filename='output_pansharpened.tif')
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that gets me pretty close.  How would I specify the arguments with the parens to equate to this:
gdal_pansharpen.py LC80420362016085LGN00_B8.TIF LC80420362016085LGN00_B4.TIF LC80420362016085LGN00_B3.TIF LC80420362016085LGN00_B2.TIF carrizo-20160325-oli-pan.tif -r bilinear -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGB
assuming I have the images stored as local variables b8, b4, b3, b2, and tif?

Would it be equal to this?
gdal_pansharpen([b8, b4, b3, b2, tif, '-r', 'bilinear', '-co', 'COMPRESS=DEFLATE', '-co', 'PHOTOMETRIC=RGB'])

Comment: Yea, turns out I also needed to specify the -nodata flag as well, otherwise the image was messed up due to the nodata messing with the overall statistics of the image.  Unfortunately, the multi band format pansharpen call has a bug where you can't specify nodata, but the vrt route then calling it works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: i use this solution but there is an other error : ERROR 4: 1: No such file or directory. why??

Answer (score 2):

```
ERROR 4: 3: No such file or directory
```

I think code should be:

```
from osgeo.scripts.gdal_pansharpen import gdal_pansharpen
gdal_pansharpen(['', '-b', '1', '-b', '2', '-b', '3', 'input_pan.tif', 'input_multi.tif', 'output_pansharpened.tif'])
```

`''` is `argv[0]`.