# Importing gdal_pansharpen in Python

Tags: python, gdal, import

I imported gdal module but I can't find gdal_pansharpen function in gdal. How can I import this function in Python?

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

Comment: Does this question provide an answer? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353605/calling-gdal-pansharpen-py-from-another-python-script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling gdal\_pansharpen.py from another Python script?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353605/calling-gdal-pansharpen-py-from-another-python-script)

Comment: What is osgeo version?

Comment: my gdal version is 3.1.4

Comment: Thanks ycartwhelen, that's useful information.

Answer (score 5):

After updating gdal, use this:

```
from osgeo_utils import gdal_pansharpen  # for GDAL >= 3.3

# OR
# from osgeo.utils import gdal_pansharpen # for GDAL == 3.2
```

Comment: I tried both, and it can not find this module

Comment: Thanks Kadir, that works. I upgrade my gdal version to 3.3.1. so now i can import gdal_pansharpen module.

Answer (score 3):

I updated gdal version to 3.3.1 by running following:

```
conda create -n gdal python=3.8
conda activate gdal
conda install gdal -c conda-forge
```

and to import the module, what I did is:

```
from osgeo_utils.gdal_pansharpen import gdal_pansharpen
```

I found that the function only work if I leave the first argument as blank.

with seperate bands:

```
gdal_pansharpen(['', pan_tif, band1_tif, band2_tif, band3_tif, out_tif])
```

with multi band:

```
gdal_pansharpen(['', '-b', '1', '-b', '2', '-b', '3', pan_tif, multi_band, out_tif])
```