# gdal_pansharpen.py raise module errors

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo, jupyter-notebook, pansharpening

I want to use gdal pansharpen python function. I have two tif files, one is the panachromatic raster and on is the 4 bands raster. I'm using **gdal version 3.4.0**.
I have tried to use it, [based on this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353605/calling-gdal-pansharpen-py-from-another-python-script), like this:

```
from osgeo_utils import gdal_pansharpen
gdal_pansharpen(
    pan_name='the/path/for/the/pan_img.TIF',    
    spectral_names=['the/path/for/the/spect_img.TIF'], 
    band_nums=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    dst_filename='output_pansharpened.tif')
```

However, this raised error:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Then I have tried the other version that appears in the post, which suppose to be good for older versions of gdal, howevr I have tried it:

```
from osgeo.scripts.gdal_pansharpen import gdal_pansharpen
gdal_pansharpen(['', '-b', '1', '-b', '2', '-b', '3', '-b', '4', 'path/for/the/pan_img.TIF', 'path/for/spect_img.TIF', 'output_pansharpened.tif'])
```

However that also raised an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo.scripts'

I have to say that when I run this on QGIS gdal pansharpening tool it worked no problem. Now I would like to do the same with python.
Please help me find the cause of that error.
If need more information I would love to help.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable. But do you really need to import gdal_pansharpen.py into your own Python code? For simple tasks you can run the script standalone as `python gdal_pansharpen.py` https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_pansharpen.html.

Comment: @user30184 I'm  a bit confused regard the running it as standalone, where should it be run ?

Comment: https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/#using-the-python-command.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
from osgeo_utils.gdal_pansharpen import gdal_pansharpen
```